# Google frontend server reponds 400 to POST request to GCP Cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I deployed SvelteKit app to cloud function v2, which uses cloud run. When manually testing deployment's functionality, I found out, that every POST request fails with status code 400. Further inspections showed, that the request doesn't even reach my app and response indicates it is google rejected by google frontend server.
The POST requests were created by submitting form, but to eliminate possibility, there is problem with app, I tired creating POST request to my app using `curl`, but the result is the same, now it's obvious that something filters requests to my app. Probably this is something configurable I'm not aware of, but anyway, for more info:

**curl:**

```
> POST /collections/test/zEhn42fLbfWkXwvUDzFt HTTP/2
> Host: genoacms-cbahseeaka-ey.a.run.app
> User-Agent: curl/8.2.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
< HTTP/2 400 
< x-cloud-trace-context: 8aec23360d50895fb0a318d487047df8
< date: Tue, 12 Mar 2024 11:18:47 GMT
< content-type: text/html
< server: Google Frontend
< content-length: 11
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
< 
* Connection #0 to host genoacms-cbahseeaka-ey.a.run.app left intact
Bad Request
```

[image]

Note: this request made by curl doesn't have handler in app, but it didn't even reach router, where I console.log it. Response is same for "real" requests.

Comment: The fact that Google's frontend server is rejecting both your curl request and your form submissions with a 400 status code indicates that the problem might have to do with the request itself rather than your Cloud Run app.

Comment: Yes, but requests I made were respecting RFC7230 and I even tried the most simple forms of POST requests, all of them failed, where it even seemed, there was nothing that could be wrong. I also found out, that basically every method other than GET fails. I think there is problem with config, last year I deployed other app to cloud run, and everything works as charm. I compared YAML configs of both CL services, but are almost the same.

Comment: Scrutinize Cloud Run service YAML for ingress settings, timeouts, and IAM permissions. Consider deploying an older Cloud Run version or trying a different region to isolate version or regional discrepancies. Advanced tools like Cloud Monitoring and Cloud Trace can offer deeper insights. If all else fails, [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) might be your best bet.